# I add Google maps SDK and add all frameworks it works but later i will have:

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, linker

I add Google maps SDK and add all frameworks it works but later i will have (folder is create):

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/nv_user/Documents/Google' ld: warning: directory not found
>   for option '-FAPI/GoogleMaps-iOS-1.8.1' duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._googleMap in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._wwcd in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._coordinate in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._forMapsView in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._setView1 in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._setView2 in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._setView3 in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._rightButton in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._leftButton in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._pinsButton in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController._setButton in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController
>   in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController in:
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/Simple_Point_PROAppDelegate.o
>       /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Simple_Point_PRO-hhwjbvsrisxkxmcyyhsotdhyakxo/Build/Intermediates/Simple
>   Point PRO.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Simple Point
>   PRO.build/Objects-normal/i386/SimplePointPROGoogleMapViewController.o
>   ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What i can do with this?

Comment: You've got it twice. Check in your project.

Comment: I check it 5 times and I can`t search problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you need to delete the derived data. You can find it under /Users/nv_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

Comment: Check if you have used .m instead of .h while importing any class. Also check compile resources in Build Phases for duplicacy